# dplyr mutate_at function applied to multiple columns - using dynamic column names

Tags: r, dynamic, dplyr

I have a data frame x.

```
x <- data.frame(a = c(10, 20, 30, 0), b = c(1, 2, 3, 0), c = c(1, 2, 3, 0), d = c(8, 16, 24, 0))
x
denominator_var <- "a"
numerator_vars <- c("b", "c", "d")
```

Using dplyr, I'm trying to add new columns (b_share, c_share, and d_share) such that each of them are equal to the corresponding column (b, c, and d) divided into a.
However, it is important to me to use NOT the original variable names but *dynamic* variable names.

My code below is not working. What's wrong?

```
x %>% mutate_at(vars(one_of(numerator_vars)),
                funs(share = ifelse(!!(denominator_var) > 0, round(./!!(denominator_var) * 100, 2), 0)))
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `as.name` before applying `!!`:

```
x %>% mutate_at(vars(one_of(numerator_vars)), funs(share = 
  ifelse(!!(as.name(denominator_var)), round(./!!(as.name(denominator_var))) * 100, 2)))

#    a b c  d b_share c_share d_share
# 1 10 1 1  8       0       0     100
# 2 20 2 2 16       0       0     100
# 3 30 3 3 24       0       0     100
# 4  0 0 0  0       2       2       2
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Despite somewhat more typing, I prefer that solution - as it helps me avoide quo'ting

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result you want by `quo`ting your denominator beforehand:

```
denominator_var <- quo(a)
x %>% mutate_at(numerator_vars,
                funs(share = ifelse(!!(denominator_var) > 0, 
                                    round(./!!(denominator_var) * 100, 2),
                                    0)))
```

Also note that you don't need to use `vars` for your vector `numerator_vars`.